# Single-level expression of linear mixed model with addition of covariates

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme

For the `Oats` dataset in `nlme`, page 162 of "Mixed-effects models in S and S-PLUS" provided a way to express multilevel model through single-level expression in `nlme`.

More specifically, the following is a multilevel model in which `Variety` is nested in `Block` specified in the conventional way:

```
library(nlme)
fm4Oats <- lme( yield ~ nitro, data = Oats, random = ~ 1 | Block/Variety )
```

Page 162 of "Mixed-effects models in S and S-PLUS" provided the following alternative fitting strategy through single-level representation of the mixed model (R code highlighted in green, math formula also included to facilitate understanding):
[image]

I wish ask h**ow to write the code through single-level expression approach (like `fm4OatsC`) if I want to add a covariate whose random slope effect varies across levels of Variety and additionally assume a compound covariance structure between random intercept and random slope**. More specifically, I want the covariance matrix (`Psi**_new`) to be as follows:
[image]
where `sigma^2_1` and `sigma^2_2` are the same as in the book, and `sigma^2_3` is the variance for the random slope of covariate `x`, and `sigma_23` is the covariance between random intercept of Variety and random slope of `x`.

Note: There is no covariate `x` in the `Oats` data. I just wish to see how the formula should have been written in `nlme` to specify the designated `psi**_new`.

I like the single-level expression approach since it allows for more flexibility in defining the covariance structure. But I also wish to know if the following code gives the desired covariance matrix:

```
fm4Oats <- lme( yield ~ nitro, data = Oats, random = ~ x | Block/Variety )
```